# Merge a larger pandas dataframe with specific values from a subset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas DataFrame and a separate subset of that DataFrame with a value calculated. I want to merge the values of the subset DataFrame back into the larger one without changing any of the other values.

```
df_large:
index  col_1 col_2 col_3
1      10    15    33
2      23    16    nan
3      33    92    34
4      132   123   nan
5      32    59    nan
```

And a subset:

```
df_small:
index  col_1 col_2 col_3
2      23    16    34
4      132   123   87
```

I want the resulting DataFrame to overwrite the values in df_large.col_3 with values in df_small.col_3 only where the particular index exists in df_small:

```
df_large:
index  col_1 col_2 col_3
1      10    15    33
2      23    16    34
3      33    92    34
4      132   123   87
5      32    59    nan
```

I have tried looking at merge, but I'm not sure how to do this elegantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way (among many) to do it:

```
df_large.ix[df_small.index, 'col_3'] = df_small.col_3
```

it seems to be faster compared to `combine_first()`

```
In [408]: %timeit df = df_large.combine_first(df_small)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.45 ms per loop

In [409]: %timeit df_large.ix[df_small.index, 'col_3'] = df_small.col_3
100 loops, best of 3: 2.43 ms per loop
```